# Unique dictionaries out of a list of lists?

Tags: python, dictionary, duplicates, list-comprehension, nested-lists

I have a list called `matrix` which contains some rows. Each `row` contains some dictionaries, and each dictionary could be contained in more than one row.

I want to generate a list called `dictionaries` which contains all the dictionaries in the matrix, but **without duplicates**. I already have a solution, but I would like to use comprehension.

```
row1 = [{'NODE':1}, {'NODE':2}, {'NODE':3}]
row2 = [{'NODE':3}, {'NODE':4}, {'NODE':5}]
row3 = [{'NODE':4}, {'NODE':6}, {'NODE':7}]
matrix = [row1, row2, row3]

dictionaries = []
for row in matrix:
    for dictionary in row:
        items.append(dictionary) if dictionary not in dictionaries else None

print dictionaries
[{'NODE':1}, {'NODE':2}, {'NODE':3}, {'NODE':4}, {'NODE':5}, {'NODE':6}, {'NODE':7}]
```

I would like something like the following but it doesn't work since I cannot ask to check a list while I'm creating it:

```
dictionaries = [dictionary for row in matrix for dictionary in row if dictionary not in dictionaries]
```

The dictionary keys and values are primitive immutable objects like strings and integers.

Comment: Does order matter?

Comment: no it doesn't matter

Comment: So your items are *mutable* and so can't be hashed. Does the mutability *extend to nested values*? E.g. `{'NODE': {'set', 'with', 'elements'}}`? Or are all keys and values immutable?

Comment: no, it is not extended to nested values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension, but depending on your Python version, using an [`collections.OrderedDict` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) with a generator expression to flatten the matrix would actually be more efficient.

When your values are *not hashable* and thus can't be stored in a set or dictionary, you'll have to use first create an immutable representation, so we can store that representation in a set or dictionary to efficiently track uniqueness.

For dictionaries that are flat structures with all keys and values immutable, just use `tuple(sorted(d.items()))`. This produces a tuple of all `(key, value)` pairs (also tuples), in sorted order to avoid dictionary order issues.

On Python 3.5 and up, use an `OrderedDict()` that maps the immutable keys to original dictionaries:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

key = lambda d: tuple(sorted(d.items()))

dictionaries = list(OrderedDict((key(v), v) for row in matrix for v in row).values())
```

On Python 3.4 and earlier, `OrderedDict` is slow and you'd be beter of using a separate set approach for Python 3.4 and below:

```
key = lambda d: tuple(sorted(d.items()))
seen = set()
seen_add = seen.add
dictionaries = [
    v for row in matrix
    for k, v in ((key(v), v) for v in row)
    if not (k in seen or seen_add(k))]
```

Quick demo using your input data and an `OrderedDict`:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> row1 = [{'NODE':1}, {'NODE':2}, {'NODE':3}]
>>> row2 = [{'NODE':3}, {'NODE':4}, {'NODE':5}]
>>> row3 = [{'NODE':4}, {'NODE':6}, {'NODE':7}]
>>> matrix = [row1, row2, row3]
>>> key = lambda d: tuple(sorted(d.items()))
>>> list(OrderedDict((key(v), v) for row in matrix for v in row).values())
[{'NODE': 1}, {'NODE': 2}, {'NODE': 3}, {'NODE': 4}, {'NODE': 5}, {'NODE': 6}, {'NODE': 7}]
```

Comment: thanks, actually my problem was a bit more complicated, so I updated my question since it still doesn't work

Comment: @piezzoritro: right, so your items are *mutable*. That's still something we can fix.

Answer (score 1):

If you have NumPy:

```
np.unique(matrix).tolist()
```

Comment: The goal posts have moved: the matrix rows contain *dictionaries*. Will numpy still handle that case efficiently?

Comment: Just tested this and no, `np.unique()` wants to *order* the elements and that results in a `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'` exception.

Answer (score 0):

Flatten the list, then use a set to eliminate dupes.

```
print set(item for sublist in matrix for item in sublist)
```

Comment: Good point, thanks. I've removed the `[..]`. Is that what the downvote was for?

Comment: It was; thanks for updating! Any reason you are not using a `{...}` set comprehension here?

Comment: Since the rows contain dictionaries, I get an error TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Comment: Note that the goalposts have moved; the OP updated the problem, they have *unhashable dictionaries* in their matrix.