# Unique lists values in dictionary

Tags: python

I am trying to have unique lists in dictionary values. I have achieved that using this [Uniqueness for list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44309113/unique-dictionaries-out-of-a-list-of-lists)

My doubt is how do I write the data back to the dictionary. So far this is what I have done:

```
  final_dict = {'SELECT: AutoSelect DF2F': [['D80', 'FoldersDF2FAutoSelect'], ['DF90', 'FoldersDF2FAutoSelect'], ['DF80', 'FoldersDF2FAutoSelect'], ['DF90', 'PB:FoldersDF2FAutoSelect']], 'SELECT: TB70001': [['DF80', 'FolderSelected'], ['DF90', 'PB:FolderSelected'], ['DF80', 'FolderSelected'], ['DF90', 'FolderSelected']]}
    for v in final_dict.values():
        unique_data = [list(x) for x in set(tuple(x) for x in v)]
```

If you look my dictionary has so many duplicate lists a values. I have eliminated the duplicates. Now, how would I convert it back to dict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a simple iteration

Ex:

```
final_dict = {'SELECT: AutoSelect DF2F': [['D80', 'FoldersDF2FAutoSelect'], ['DF90', 'FoldersDF2FAutoSelect'], ['DF80', 'FoldersDF2FAutoSelect'], ['DF90', 'PB:FoldersDF2FAutoSelect']], 'SELECT: TB70001': [['DF80', 'FolderSelected'], ['DF90', 'PB:FolderSelected'], ['DF80', 'FolderSelected'], ['DF90', 'FolderSelected']]}
for k, v in final_dict.items():
    final_dict[k] = [list(x) for x in set(tuple(x) for x in v)]
pprint(final_dict)
```

**Output:**

```
{'SELECT: AutoSelect DF2F': [['DF90', 'FoldersDF2FAutoSelect'],
                             ['D80', 'FoldersDF2FAutoSelect'],
                             ['DF90', 'PB:FoldersDF2FAutoSelect'],
                             ['DF80', 'FoldersDF2FAutoSelect']],
 'SELECT: TB70001': [['DF90', 'PB:FolderSelected'],
                     ['DF80', 'FolderSelected'],
                     ['DF90', 'FolderSelected']]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, in the for loop, keep track of the keys `k`, and save `unique_data` in that dictionary at that key:

```
final_dict = {'SELECT: AutoSelect DF2F': [['D80', 'FoldersDF2FAutoSelect'], ['DF90', 'FoldersDF2FAutoSelect'], ['DF80', 'FoldersDF2FAutoSelect'], ['DF90', 'PB:FoldersDF2FAutoSelect']], 'SELECT: TB70001': [['DF80', 'FolderSelected'], ['DF90', 'PB:FolderSelected'], ['DF80', 'FolderSelected'], ['DF90', 'FolderSelected']]}
for k,v in final_dict:
    unique_data = [list(x) for x in set(tuple(x) for x in v)]
    final_dict[k] = unique_data
```